# Scrollview inside containerView won't scroll?

Tags: iphone, scroll, uiscrollview, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController subclass that has a container UIView which has 1 of 2 subviews: the tableview, or a UIScroll depending on whether or not the view is "flipped".

my viewDidLoad() method adds the tableview to the container:

```
[kContainerView addSubview: self.tableView];
self.view = kContainerView;
```

and initializes the UIScrollview with an 900x600 image and sets itself as the delegate:

```
kSBCanvasScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];  
[kSBCanvasScrollView setDelegate: self];
kSBImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
[kSBCanvasScrollView addSubview:kSBImage];
[kSBCanvasScrollView setContentSize:[img size]];    
[kSBCanvasScrollView setMinimumZoomScale:0.5];
```

The the front "Table side" of the view works fine.  I then flip the view when the user selects a button on the toolbar by doing the following:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0f];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

if (kSBCanvasIsVisible==NO) {
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:kContainerView cache:YES];
    [self.tableView removeFromSuperview];
    [kContainerView addSubview:kSBCanvasScrollView];
    kSBCanvasIsVisible = YES;
} else {
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:kContainerView cache:YES];
    [kSBCanvasScrollView removeFromSuperview];
    [kContainerView addSubview:self.tableView];
    kSBCanvasIsVisible = NO;
}
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

It flips just like I want, but the kSBCanvasScrollView does not scroll.  The pinch gesture works.  Why won't the view scroll?  Perhaps it relates to the fact this is a TableViewController?

Comment: i believe for scroll view to work correctly it must have a frame size of larger than an iphone screen. It doesn't look like your setting the frame size here. I can post some code from my app if you like.

Comment: Actually for the scrollView to be able to scroll, it has a smaller frame than its content. OP, what did you use for bounds
 and can you make sure it is bigger than [img size]?

Answer (score 0):

Is your scrollview 320 x 460? I had to make the scroll view the same , or smaller than the iphone screen for it to work(In IB but not necessarily in the

```
[kSBCanvasScrollView setContentSize:[img size];).
```

Did you write:

```
[kSBCanvasScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
```

PS: I did try this. It worked for me...